# Script to Copy all text from multiple Word Documents into seperate cells in a single Excel Document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy all the text, with formatting intact, from each of multiple Word Documents, and paste the text of each into a new cell in a single Excel Spreadsheet, placing the name of the Word Doc in an adjacent cell.
So the file name of "Document 1" goes in cell A1, and the entire contents of "Document 1" goes in cell A2.
We have several hundred Documents that need to be imported onto pages on our new corporate Intranet, and the migration tool provided only works off data in an Excel workbook.
I've checked out a number of threads, videos, and searches and tried to cobble together a couple of different attempts but neither is working. The first, if it did work, may not handle the File Name copy and it seems to run into issues with selecting the destination cell for the copy.
The second seems to be exactly what I want, but I can;t get the Paste into Excel bit working.

The first runs into an issue when it hits the "Range("LastRow").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" line, saying the range is invalid (I have defined "LastRow" in the Excel Workbook but it doesn't help) :

```
Sub Copy_Data_From_Multiple_WordFiles()
Dim FolderName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim NewWordFile As New Word.Application
Dim NewDoc As New Word.Document
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FolderName = "C:\Test\"
FileName = Dir(FolderName)
'Loop start
Do While FileName ⋖⋗ ""
    Set NewDoc = NewWordFile.documents.Open(FolderName & FileName) 
    NewDoc.Range(0, NewDoc.Range.End).Copy
    Range("LastRow").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    NewDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    NewWordFile.Quit    
FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

NB: LastRow is defined in Excel Name Manager as:=OFFSET(CopyDataFromWord!$A$1,COUNTA(CopyDataFromWord!$A:$A),0,1,1)

I have tried a second set of code I got from a post on here, which should be closer to what I'm seeking, but again, won't quite get there. This one fails with a "Run-Time error '424': Object Required" at the line where it should paste into Excel. It doesn't seem to be recognising the Object "objDoc"?

```
   Sub Excel_Word()
    Dim WordApp As Object 'New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Object ' New Word.Document
    Dim Range As Object 'Word.Range
    Dim WordDoc As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    
    sPath = "C:\Users\jdodd\Documents\Cleaned\"
    
 WordDoc = Dir(sPath & "*.docx")
   
    Do While WordDoc <> ""
        Set objDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(sPath & WordDoc)
        
        objDoc.Range.Copy
           
            i = i + 1
            ImportPolicyfromWord.Cells(i, 1).Value = objDoc
            ImportPolicyfromWord.Cells(i, 2).Value = objDoc.Range.PasteSpecial
         
        WordDoc = Dir()
    Loop
    
    WordApp.Quit

    'elimina variabili
    'Set WordApp = Nothing
    'Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Appreciate any advice or help

Comment: That simply isn't going to happen. At most you will get bold, italic & similar content from the document body, but headers, footers, endnotes, footnotes, tables, graphics, etc. can't be captured that way.

Comment: That's fine. There are no headers or footers, no images, all tables are being stripped out using a different script. Its really just fonts, bolding/italics, bullet points and hyperlinks. Is there any fix to the script to at least get most of the content transferred as best as possible? With 700+ files to be migrated, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub GetDocData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then GoTo ErrExit
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strFile As String, WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
'Disable any auto macros in the documents being processed
wdApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
'Disable any alerts in the documents being processed
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    .ConvertNumbersToText (wdNumberAllNumbers)
    With .Range.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Text = "[^12^13^l]{1,}"
      .Replacement.Text = "¶"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      .Text = "[^t]"
      .Replacement.Text = " "
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    r = WkSht.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If r > 1 Then r = r + 2
    WkSht.Range("A" & r).Value = .Name
    .Range.Copy
    r = r + 1
    WkSht.Paste Destination:=WkSht.Range("A" & r)
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
ErrExit:
wdApp.Quit
WkSht.UsedRange.Replace What:="¶", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Simply select the folder to process. As coded, the macro places the document name above the contents, which are all pasted into one cell. If you want the document name on the same row, but beside the contents, change:

```
    r = r + 1
    WkSht.Paste Destination:=WkSht.Range("A" & r)
```

to:

```
    WkSht.Paste Destination:=WkSht.Range("B" & r)
```

Comment: Thank YOU!! Activated the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library in References. I amended ".doc" to ".docx" cause they're DocX files. I remove "strFile" from the line "WkSht.Name = Split(strFile, ".docx")(0)" because it wasgiving a '1004' error stating "You typed an invalid name for a sheet or chart...". Also amended  "If r > 1 Then r = r + 2" to " If r > 1 Then r = r + 1"  to remove the blank line between entries. The modification to move the name to the cell beside worked perfectly.
This will work. Legend!

Comment: « I amended ".doc" to ".docx" cause they're DocX files». That's fine, but".doc" would pick up .doc, .docx and .docm files. «"WkSht.Name = Split(strFile, ".docx")(0)"» oops - left over from another project. Code revised. «Also amended "If r > 1 Then r = r + 2" to " If r > 1 Then r = r + 1" to remove the blank line between entries» That's fine - the +2 allowed clear space between entries. Your choice.

Comment: seems to need the change to .docx to run. Also seems weirdly glitchy: 1st time I run the default script above it works fine. Then modify it to use the optional replacement "WkSht.Paste " & it works once exporting content to the 26th row. Run a 2nd time & it only puts the last file in the folder, in row 1, & ignores the rest. Remove that alternate "WkSht.Paste" text & restore to the default & it will work again, then paste back in the alternate text & that will work. Seems to require editing the code everytime it's run. This behaviour happens everytime! It's really weird!!

Comment: It seems there's something weird with your system or your implementation of the suggested changes. In my testing, when the macro is run a 2nd or 3rd time, for example, the new entries simply go below the old ones. The only other possibility - which might reflect rows being overridden (if, despite what you said, some documents are more complex than you indicated), is the initial r calculation. Code revised to take account of that possibility.